# update the related list records using anonymous block

Tags: apex, soql

I have a requirement wherein an object account has 3 related list records as opportunity,accountplan and callreport. I want to update all three objects fields associated with the account. But getting error:

> System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject

Following Code :

```
List<Account> accList=[select id,Restricted_View__c,IsRequest_Restricted_disable__c,(Select Id, Name From contacts),(select Id,name from Opportunities),(select Id,name from Call_Reports__r),(select id,name form Account_Plans) from account where Restricted_View__c=true and IsRequest_Restricted_disable__c=true];

List<Call_Report__c> callrepoList=new List<Call_Report__c>();
List<Account_Plan__c> accplansList=new List<Account_Plan__c>();
List<Opportunity> oppsList=new List<Opportunity>(); 

for(Account acc:accList){
    acc.Restricted_View__c=false;
    acc.IsRequest_Restricted_disable__c=false;
    callrepoList.add(acc.Call_Reports__r);
    accplansList.add(acc.Account_Plans__r);
    oppsList.add(acc.Opportunities);
}
update accList;

//Unlock all the associated callreports

for(Call_Report__c callrepos:callrepoList){
    callrepos.Restricted_View__c=false;
}
update callrepoList;

//Unlock all the account plans
for(Account_Plan__c accpln:accplansList){
    accpln.Restricted_View__c=false;
}
update accplansList;
```

Comment: It looks like you are getting this error in somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 2):

The error doesnt come from that fragment of code. It is thrown when you are assigning a single sOBject to a query that returns more than 1 result.

P.e:

```
Order o = [SELECT Id FROM Order];
```

By the case you find where the error is being thrown (You can see it in the logs, exceptions, etc), here are 2 workarounds:

- Being sure you will recieve only 1 result, for example, filtering by Id:

  Order o = [SELECT Id FROM Order WHERE Id = :orderId];
- Adding LIMIT 1, be carefull with the logic of your code as this couldnt be what you are looking for.

  Order o = [SELECT Id FROM Order LIMIT 1];

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the first line:

```
List<Account> accList=[select id,Restricted_View__c,IsRequest_Restricted_disable__c,
(Select Id, Name From contacts),(select Id,name from Opportunities),
(select Id,name from Call_Reports__r),(select id,name form Account_Plans) from account 
where Restricted_View__c=true and IsRequest_Restricted_disable__c=true];
```

in this part of the first line: `(select id,name form Account_Plans)`
you have to:

- Change `form` to `from`;
- Double-check the name `Account_Plans`: I think it is missing the suffix `__r`